# "We shall be preparing tea" or "We shall be making tea"

Tags: grammar, verbs, sentence-structure

Can anyone please tell me which one is correct to say

> We shall be preparing tea.

or

> We shall be making tea.

Comment: Both are correct.  Though if you meant to say that there will be tea to drink, generally you'd want to say that "we'll be having tea".  The actual *making* of the tea is implicit in that case.  Talking about the *preparation* or *making* of tea doesn't actually imply the *drinking* of the tea afterwards.

Comment: ...and *shall* is an overly formal expression. So, unless it's going to be a very posh event, *will* or the contraction *'ll* fits better.

Answer (score 1):

Both are technically correct.

> We shall be preparing tea.

sounds, to an American ear, distinctly formal and somewhat pretentious.

> We shall be making tea.

is less so, but "making" is a more casual and utilitarian word, so I'd be inclined to expect

> We'll be making tea.

Answer (score 0):

Both your examples are correct. Also, they both refer strictly to the process of mixing water, plants, (optionally) spices and heat in order to get tea in the end.

Your examples do not tell anything about the purpose of the making of the tea: just drinking, having a party, doing some kind of experiment, bottling and selling it...

Some may argue that "prepare" is more suitable for "tea", because "make" is more related to constructing (something). This is not a big issue though, and "make tea" is still perfectly suitable.

Comment: By the way, the process of letting the tea steep in hot water to extract the flavor is called brewing. _Brew_ may be used both as the verb for the process and the noun for the drink prepared by brewing. So tea is a brew, Brewing it is a decisive step in preparing it.